# How can I keep class active after refreshing the page (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching for whole day and found several examples but none of them work correctly. I have a navigation bar and I want to keep class `active` after clicking on it and refreshing page but it gets lost.

This is my code:

## HTML

```
<li class="sub-menu" style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey;">
    <a class="menuItem active" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Administrator")">
        <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
        <span>Index</span>
    </a>
</li>

 <li class="sub-menu">
    <a class="menuItem normal" href="@Url.Action("Products", "Administrator")">                     
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <span>product</span>
    </a>
 </li>
```

## Javascript

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('classChange');

if (retrievedObject) {
    $('.menuItem').addClass(retrievedObject)
}

$(".menuItem").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("normal")) {
        $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem('classChange', 'active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('normal');
        localStorage.setItem('classChange', 'normal');
    }
});
```

I expected to change class on active after click but all classes change after click, I understand why it happens but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think your js code won't even run. Use an alert to get sure that the code inside the click handler runs. Since you provide the anchor with a url to redirect, I think it has priority over the on click event

Comment: on alert it works, first it alerts and after redirects

Answer (score 0):

Can you give each element an id value and, in the function, store in the local storage the id of the element and the class? Then, on reload check for the both id's?

And if you need for more elements you can save an array of the id's and then use it to loop between all id's if necessary.

So something like this:

```
var ids = ['id1','id2'];
for(i of ids) {
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem(i);
    if (retrievedObject) {
        var id = "#" + i;
        $(id).addClass(retrievedObject);
    }
}

$(".menuItem").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("normal")) {
        $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem('classChange', 'active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('normal');
        localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, 'normal');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it will be better to set sessionStorage rather than localStorage. Because when user revisits the page (i.e not refresh but close page and open again), you would want to give the initial state of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
if (retrievedObject) {
    $('.menuItem').addClass(retrievedObject)
}
```

should be wrapped on jQuery.ready().